# Navigation Link in bar Items goes back to top of NavigationView

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

```
struct Testing: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack {
                Text("View 1")
                Text("View 1.3")
            
                NavigationLink(destination: TestView(),
                                    label: {
                                        Text("View 1 navigation")
                                    })
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TestView: View {

    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Text("View 2")
            }
            .navigationBarItems(trailing:NavigationLink(
                                    destination: Text("View 3"),
                                    label: {
                                        Text("Navigate")
                                     }))
    }
}
```

When clicking the `NavigationLink` inside of TestViews `navigationBarItems` it navigates to View 3. When I click the back button it does not go back to TestView it goes all the way back to Testing instead.

How do I make it go back to the previous view instead of the first view?

I am using Xcode 12.

Comment: It works fine for me on Xcode12, maybe there is something else?

Comment: I don't have anything else inside this file besides the `PreviewProvider` which is just used for the live preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put navigation link into body of navigation view (bar is not in navigation view)

So here is possible approach

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State private var isActive = false

    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Text("View 2")
            }
            .background(
               NavigationLink(destination: Text("View 3"), isActive: $isActive,
                label: { EmptyView() })
            )
            .navigationBarItems(trailing:
               Button("Navigate", action: { self.isActive = true }))
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this and it currently does not navigate to View 3 when pressed. I put a print statement inside of the `Button` action with the isActive toggle and it is getting pressed, but the navigation is not working.

Comment: Fixed - typed here and forgot one argument. See updated. Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14.

Comment: This works exactly how I want. Would I have to do this type of logic for every view I want to have a `NavigationLink` be triggered when a bar button is clicked? Seems like the code would get pretty messy with the more bar buttons you have.

Comment: NavigationLink should be in body to be placed in stack of NavigationView, how you design it for reuse, is up to you. Moreover, keep in mind that navigationBarItems modifier is deprecated in favour of toolbar since iOS 14. Just be aware.