# Back button skipping a view in View1 -> View2 -> View3 NavigationLink

Tags: swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui

I'm fairly new to Swift and it may be I'm going about this all wrong, but I have a bug I can't work out - within a NavigationView, a NavigationLink in View1 opens to View 2, then that view has a NavigationLink to View3. View3 shows the title from View1, which is obviously wrong, and when the back button is pressed it also goes back to View1 rather than View2. Am I using these links wrong or is it a SwiftUI issue? Simplified example of what I'm doing below.

```
struct FirstView: View {
   var body: some View {
      Text("Hello, World #1!")
        .navigationBarItems(trailing:
            NavigationLink(destination: SecondView()){
                Image(systemName: "folder.badge.plus")
            }
        )
   }
}

struct SecondView: View {
   var body: some View {
      Text("Hello, World #2!")
        .navigationBarItems(trailing:
            NavigationLink(destination: ThirdView()){
                Image(systemName: "folder.badge.plus")
            }
        )
   }
}

struct ThirdView: View {
   var body: some View {
      Text("Hello, World #3!")
   }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/64032452/12299030. NovigationLink should be inside NavigationView, not in bar.

Comment: Thanks that looks like my issue! Not seen that way of using links (.background) before :)

Comment: Also you are missing in the first view a NavigationView! See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Funny enough I had the same problem with the navigation skipping one view. Your problem is different though. The first view only will have the `NavigationView` declared. After that you just use navigation links.

Refactoring:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct FirstView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Hello, World #1!")
                    .padding()
                NavigationLink(destination: SecondView()){
                    Image(systemName: "folder.badge.plus")
                }
            }
            // a navigationBarTitle modifier inside!
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Hello"))
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, World #2!")
                .padding()
            NavigationLink(destination: ThirdView()){
                Image(systemName: "folder.badge.plus")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ThirdView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World #3!")
    }
}

struct FirstView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FirstView()
    }
}
```